# How to write multiple view function for single page

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to perform multiple operation for single web page. I'm struggling to write multiple function view for single web page. How to do that. Help me in that.

```
def home_view(request):
   if 'username' in request.session:
        if request.method == 'GET':
             form = ProfileForm(request.GET)
             if form.is_valid:
                 profile_info = Profile.objects.filter(username=username).values()
                 for i in profile_info:
                      profiledict = i
                      return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'profile_first_name': profiledict['first_name'],
                                                               'profile_last_name': profiledict["last_name"],
                                                               'profile_phone_number': profiledict['phone_number'],
                                                               'profile_email': profiledict['email'],
                                                               'profile_address': profiledict['address'],
                                                               'profile_image': profiledict['image']})
         elif request.method == 'POST':
             first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
             last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
             phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
             email = request.POST.get('email')
             address = request.POST.get('address')
             image = request.FILES['images']
             file_storage = FileSystemStorage()
             obj = Profile.objects.all().filter(username=username)
             if len(obj) > 0:
                 obj.update(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number,
                               email=email, address=address, image=file_storage.save(image.name, image))
                 return redirect('/home/')
             return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        return redirect('/login/')

def home2_view(request):
    if 'username' in request.session:
          business_objs = AddBusiness.objects.all().values()
          return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'business_objs': business_objs})
    else:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

I tried like this, it performing only first operation. Here i'm trying to perform 3 operation, GET(extract data from database and displaying in HTML form), POST(updating the form data), and Displaying all database rows and columns in HTML page.

Comment: Your view doesn't make sense.  First, you have `if username in request.session ... elif username in request.session`.  It will never get to the elif.  Second you've got if `request.method =='GET' form= ProfileForm(request.POST)` (but there is no POST.  Try sorting the logic first

Comment: Sorry my bad, Now i have two function how to perform both function in single HTML page.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. If you have a username and it is a POST but len(obj) <= 0 then you don't return anything

Comment: sorry, thanks for correcting me.